# python: how to write output of for loop into variable

Tags: variables, for-loop

I would like to write the output of a for loop stepwise into a variable named word.
The for loop looks like this:

```
text = visual.TextStim(win=win, units='pix', height=20, font='Courier')    
for i in range(len(word)):#calls upon the number of letters within a word
               text.setText(word[i])#addresses a letter within a word
               text.setPos()#give the letter a certain position on the screen
               word=...
```

I would like to write each letter one by one to a variable called word. How can I do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

letters = ['a','b', 'c']

for i in letters :
    word = word + i